# How to scale a plot using wxpython?

Tags: python-2.7, plot, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am developing an GUI which plot a line between two points that the user selects. And it has a background plot of all the lines connecting all the points(it is bind with the  wx.EVT_PAINT so it won't disappear when resizing)

However I cannot find a way to scale these plot as I resize the frame. The plot always stays the same size.

Anyone know how to enlarge or shrink the plot proportionally as I resize the frame? Does sizer work here? Thanks for any help!

[This is the original size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDvnS.png)

[This is what it looks like when I shrink it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGYsv.png)

Comment: Are you positioning the wxPoints statically or dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the coordinates you use for your points. If you want the plot to always fit into your window, the simplest would be to use the coordinate space `[0, 1]x[0, 1]` and use [wxDC::SetLogicalScale()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html#aae1c728cdd2f43601f876b7d67067a39) with `GetClientSize().x` and `.y` as parameters.

Notice that you will also need to invalidate your window in `wxEVT_SIZE` handler.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Thank VZ for the answer, which looks better than my solution.

I first normalize the coordinates of those points by dividing them with maximum x and y among all points.

Then in the 'print' function I used the GetSize() function and multiply by the normalized coordinates.